# Would there be some logs on Windows 10 about why a monitor is going blank?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Windows 10 machine with an nVidia GeForce RTX 3090 powering 3 Gigabyte Aorus FI32U monitors connected with Ivanky Display Port cables (https://ivanky.com/products/4k-displayport-1-2-cable-braided, the 5M version). They all randomly turn black every now and then and when they come back they show the OSD like if the cable was just plugged.

Is there a way to know what's causing it? Are there any logs on Windows 10 that my shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows logs are accessed via the utility named the Event Viewer.
You may find it in the Start menu.

Locating the relevant messages may require some digging in.

See the article
[What Is the Windows Event Viewer, and How Can I Use It?](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, just from this and the article, I have no idea what to look for and after going around for an hour I couldn't find anything remotely relevant to my monitors going blank.

Comment: Use "Create Custom View..." to create a view of *all* the events from the last hour, and run the Event Viewer immediately after this happens. I can give more detailed instructions if you get stuck.